# Using AppleScript to Select a File

Tags: macos, file, select, copy, applescript

I'm trying to get AppleScript to select a file, but I'm getting an error when I execute the script.

Here's the code

```
tell application "System Events"
    set a to "/Users/me/files/"
    set fileName to "myFile.jpg"
    set thePath to POSIX path of a
    tell application "Finder"
        set selection to fileName of thePath
    end tell
    keystroke "c" using command down
end tell
```

I'm getting an error "Can’t get POSIX path of "/Users/me/files/"

Essentially, what I'm trying to do is find a way to select a file so that I can copy it for later. But I want to copy the actual file, not the path of the file. The idea is to create a service that copies the file so that I can paste it into another application easily.

If there's a better way to do this, then please let me know

Comment: 1. `a` is already a `POSIX path` so `set thePath to POSIX path of a` is not needed. 2. `POSIX path` in the context of **System Events** is "(text, r/o) : the POSIX file system path of the disk item" meaning you can't `set` it, only `get` it in that context. 3. `tell application "Finder"` should not be with the `tell application "System Events"` _block_ and in the context of **Finder** `selection` is "(specifier) : the selection in the frontmost Finder window", so as a _specifier_ you can `get` it not `set` it! This is just some of what's wrong with your script, not all that is wrong.

Comment: If you want to select it in **Finder** then you need to use e.g.: reveal POSIX file "/path/to/file"`

Answer (score 0):

These following 2 lines of code would copy your file to the clipboard.  This would only work with a single file. Not multiple items.

```
activate
set the clipboard to POSIX file (POSIX path of (choose file))
```